# How to show all local minimizers?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to minimize $ \sum_{k=1}^{6}-(k\sin[(k + 1) x + k])$ , $x\in[-10,10]$ by using the command below.
`NMinimize[f[x], {x}, Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"]`
This function has 22 minimizes. 3 of them are global minimizers.
The result given by mathematica is `{-16.5322, {x -> -0.5581}}` (one of the global solution).

My question is, how to show all the minimizers by using `"SimulatedAnnealing"` or other methods such as `"RandomSearch"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NMinimize` finds (global) minima. However, you are looking for local minima, i.e. stationary points with positive curvature. So you may want to use

```
dsum[x_] = D[-Sum[(k Sin[(k + 1) x + k]), {k, 1, 6}], x];
ddsum[x_] = Simplify[D[sum[x], x]];
red = Reduce[sum[x] == 0 \[And] ddsum[x] > 0 \[And] x >= -10 \[And] x <= 10, x];
Length[red]
Apply[List, Map[N[Last[#]] &, red]]
```

This gives you 22 solutions:

```
 {-2.518992492757427, -8.802177799937013, 3.764192814422159,-1.6297820274089978, -7.9129673345885845,4.653403279770588, -0.5580997846287081,-6.841285091808294, 5.725085522550878,0.36509927663411146, -5.918086030545474,6.648284583813698, 1.2183337974144448,-5.064851509765141, 7.501519104594031,2.0654526381291416, -4.217732669050445,8.348637945308727, 2.912363387182773,-9.6540072271764,-3.3708219199968132,9.195548694362358}
```

Comment: Is that possible to apply simulated annealing but not positive curvature in your code?

Comment: you may also search for minima of `Abs[dsum[x]]` with these methods, but I'd worry that Mathematica won't find all local minima, hence `Reduce` appears more appropriate to me

Comment: By any chance, do you know how to find all the global minimizers? See linked question for details.