# How to show all global minimizers?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting, numerical-value, findinstance

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240863/finding-multiple-minimizers) and I'm aware of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144549/how-to-show-all-local-minimizers) for the local minimizers case.

Consider, for $0\leq \epsilon\leq 1$ and $0<q,p<1$, the function
$$
\begin{align}
    f(\epsilon,q,p)&=\frac{(1-\epsilon)}{3}\left[\cos\left(2\pi  q\right)+\cos\left(2\pi  p\right)+\cos\left(2\pi\left(q+p\right)\right)\right]\nonumber\\
    &\hspace{5mm}+\frac{\epsilon}{6}\bigg[\cos\left(4\pi q\right)+\cos\left(2\pi (p-q)\right) + \cos\left(4\pi p\right)\nonumber\\
    &\hspace{10mm}+\cos\left(2\pi\left(2q+p\right)\right)+\cos\left(2\pi\left(q+2p\right)\right)+\cos\left(4\pi\left(q+p\right)\right) \bigg]
\end{align}
$$

Given, in Mathematica, as

```
f = Function[{e, q, p},
  ((1 - e)/3) (Cos[2 Pi q] + Cos[2 Pi p] + 
  Cos[2 Pi (q + p)]) + (e/6) (Cos[4 Pi q] + Cos[2 Pi (q - p)] + 
  Cos[4 Pi p] + Cos[2 Pi (2 q + p)] + Cos[2 Pi (q + 2 p)] + 
  Cos[4 Pi (q + p)])];
```

For each $\epsilon$, I want to find all (or as many as possible) **global** minimizing pairs $(q,p)$ of $f$. For example, following the methodology in my [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240863/finding-multiple-minimizers), I can use inbuilt functions like `Minimize`, `NMinimize` or `FindInstance` to get some results, but I was wondering whether there is a better way. Doing so in the case $\epsilon=0$, for instance, I get the minimizing pairs $(1/3,1/3)$ and $(2/3,2/3)$ with the following code

```
eps = 0; n = 10;
min = NMinimize[{f[eps, q, p], 0 < q < 1 && 0 < p < 1}, {q, p}];
FindInstance[{f[eps, q, p] == N[Rationalize[min[[1]]]], 
  0 < q < 1 && 0 < p < 1}, {q, p}, n]
```

However, for other values of $\epsilon$ (for example $0.6$ and $0.8$), this fails. `FindInstance` does not return anything, though at least one minimizer is found is found via `NMinimize`. What is happening? Plotting $f$ for $0.6$ and $0.8$ seems to suggest that there are more than one global minimizers, but I can't find them

```
Plot3D[f[0.6, q, p], {q, 0, 1}, {p, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[f[0.8, q, p], {q, 0, 1}, {p, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

By doing it in the *tradicional manner*, that is, finding the gradient and Hessian, one could hope to get better results (though this would include local minima, if not coincident with the global minimum), and this was suggested [before](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/240886/64001), but it does not seem to work as well due to some limitations of `Solve` or `NSolve`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f = Function[{e, q, 
    p}, ((1 - e)/3) (Cos[2 Pi q] + Cos[2 Pi p] + Cos[2 Pi (q + p)]) + (e/
       6) (Cos[4 Pi q] + Cos[2 Pi (q - p)] + Cos[4 Pi p] + 
       Cos[2 Pi (2 q + p)] + Cos[2 Pi (q + 2 p)] + Cos[4 Pi (q + p)])];

{min, arg} = NMinimize[{f[6/10, q, p], 0 < q < 1, 0 < p < 1}, {q, p}]

(* {-0.220032, {q -> 0.193389, p -> 0.193389}} *)
```

So the global minimum must be less than `-0.22`

Use [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) to do a grid search for the critical points. Use [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) to eliminate maximums. And use [`DeleteDuplicates`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html) to remove redundancies.

```
sol = DeleteDuplicates[
  Select[(FindRoot[{D[f[6/10, q, p], p] == 0, 
         D[f[6/10, q, p], q] == 0}, {{q, #[[1]]}, {p, #[[2]]}}, 
        WorkingPrecision -> 25] & /@ 
      Flatten[Outer[{#1, #2} &, Range[0, 1, 1/10], Range[0, 1, 1/10]], 
       1]), (f[6/10, q, p] /. #) < -0.22 &] /. 
   x_?NumericQ :> Round[x, 10.^-15]]

(* {{q -> 0.193389, p -> 0.193389}, {q -> 0.193389, 
  p -> 0.613221}, {q -> 0.386779, p -> 0.806611}, {q -> 0.613221, 
  p -> 0.193389}, {q -> 0.806611, p -> 0.386779}, {q -> 0.806611, 
  p -> 0.806611}} *)
```

Verifying,

```
f[6/10, q, p] /. sol

(* {-0.220032, -0.220032, -0.220032, -0.220032, -0.220032, -0.220032} *)

Show[
 Plot3D[f[6/10, q, p], {q, 0, 1}, {p, 0, 1},
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4],
  ClippingStyle -> None],
 Graphics3D[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[{q, p, f[6/10, q, p]} /. sol]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: If I use `min` as you define (that is, $-0.220032...$) instead of $-0.22$, `sol` returns `{}`. Any idea why this happens? What would be an automatic rounding procedure?

Comment: Also, why are you using $6/10$? 0.6 is not working.

Comment: To use `min` you need to change the test to `<=` rather than `<`. Although since the `NMinimize` was done with machine precision, in some cases you might run into precision issues in the comparison. In general it might be better to use a two argument form of `Ceiling` in the test. Using `6/10` rather than `0.6` (a machine precision number) avoids `FindRoot::precw` warnings when specifying a `WorkingPrecision`. In general I recommend entering any known values as exact. This allows for specifying whatever desired `WorkingPrecision` in subsequent calculations.